# How to create custom widget plugin for Qt Designer in both Debug and Release mode

Tags: c++, qt, widget, designer

I use Qt Creator v5.13.1 with Kit Desktop Qt 5.13.1 MSVC2017 32bit to create a custom widget plugin for Qt Designer, it is a LED widget. I have two dlls: led**d**.dll (debug) and led.dl (release). I know that i must put dll in this directory so that Qt Creator can load it:

C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer

If i put led.dll in that directory and build my application (Qt Creator) in Release mode then my application runs OK but build in Debug mode then application will go to crash

If i put led**d**.dll int that directory, Qt Designer can not load the plugin and i get an error message:

*The plugin 'C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/designer/ledd.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)*

Problem that Qt Desginer can not load a plugin that is built in debug mode. if Led widget is not built in debug mode, my application (using LED widget) can not buid in debug mode too.

How can i tell Qt Designer when it should load ledd.dll (debug) and when it should load led.dll (release) so that i can build my project in debug and release modes?

Comment: Have you try to add the source in your project to debug it ?

Comment: No, i will give a try and tell you result

Comment: @ThibautB. I tried to debug and got the log of debug like this, it is very long so i posted it on Pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/EbkZF7k2

Comment: When you use a plugin, you have to use a version of Qt that is compiled with the same version of the compiler use to compile your plugin, maybe you can also check this.

Comment: You can also try to create a folder here: `C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015\include\QtCustomPlugin` and add your source in. And try to add it in your `.pro` file